# ¿Gramatica Simbolos Terminales y no Terminales PYTHON?

Tags: python

Me encuentro realizando un programa para mi clase de autómatas. Pero ahora nos han pedido un programa un tanto complicado y me gustaría que me ayudasen con un detalle.(No busco que me hagan la tarea, mas bien busco que me aporten ideas)
El problema es, que en la siguiente gramática:

```
program > begin statementlist end
statementlist > statement statementtail
statementtail > statement statementtail
statementtail > 
statement > ip dosp igual expresion pcoma
statement > read pari exprlist pard pcoma
statement > write pari exprlist pard pcoma
idlist > id idtail
idtail > coma id idtail
idtail > 
exprlist > expresion exprtail
exprtail > coma expresion exprtail
exprtail > 
expresion > primary primarytail
primarytail > addop primary primarytail
primarytail > 
primary > pari expresion pard
primary > id
primary > intliteral
addop > mas
addop > menos
systemgoal > program
```

Tengo símbolos terminales y no terminales. Hasta ahí todo claro.
La actividad propone realizar un programa capaz de leer desde un txt la gramática mostrada y ademas separar los símbolos terminales de los no terminales. (Básicamente separar el lado izquierdo del derecho).
Todo esto lo intenté hacer con listas, pero no me funcionó.
Un detalle importante es que NO TENGO PERMITIDO USAR SPLIT().
Alguna idea? Cualquier aporte será agradecido.

Comment: No entiendo por qué no se te permite usar `split()`, ya que es obvio que necesitas esa funcionalidad para separar el lado izquierdo del derecho por donde aparezca el  `>`, y también para separar los símbolos del lado derecho por donde aparezca el espacio. Si no te dejan usar el `str.split()`, obviamente tendrás que implementar tu propia función `split()`, pero a menos que el ejercicio _vaya precisamente de eso_ (cosa que no parece), no le veo ningún sentido a obligarte a implementar tu propio `split()`. ¿Seguro que lo has entendido bien?

Comment: En cualquier caso [aqui](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47628) tienes algunas ideas sobre cómo implementar tu propia función `split()` (más complicada que la que necesitas, pues admite varios separadores, pero puedes adaptarla a tus necesidades), por si es que el ejercicio _va de eso_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"""
Puedes evitar el uso de split, usando algunas expresiones regulares.
Tambien puedes crear alguna variable que contenga tus "palabras reservadas", y luego evaluar cada posicion de RES (del ejemplo).
"""
import re
t = "statementtail > statement statementtail"
res = re.findall("(\w+|>)", t)
#res ['statementtail', '>', 'statement', 'statementtail']
```